# How to analyze size frequency data from over 70 sites

Tags: experiment-design, biostatistics, histogram, population, frequency

[image]When I started my PhD, I had virtually no prep-time. My advisor needed me in the field and told me to go grab samples. As such, my planning wasn't the best, so sorry if this is a completely terrible question:

I have individuals of two species from 70 sites along a river (most cases 4 quadrats each, many cases of empty quadrats though). I measured individuals sizes and total site weight and density. So in effect, I have [size-frequency distributions](https://mokacytle.tumblr.com/image/174346138667).

Basically, I want to know how the size frequency changes over the course of the river, IE is there a significant shift from one species to the other (these preliminary histograms suggest yes) and how do sizes change as you move downstream? Also, I'm using jmp, which automatically sliced the river miles into five segments, is there a way to determine statistically if this an appropriate segmentation?

Comment: Good questions--but a little too unfocused and numerous for our format.  Please consider paring your post down to a definite and specific question.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your suggestion. I limited it to the central question. Please let me know if it's better this way.